# Do we still have to cite "common knowledge" questions?

Tags: discussion

This [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15116/what-is-the-significance-of-changing-the-names-of-abram-to-abraham-and-sarai-to/26312#26312) appears to be common knowledge, as it is written explicitly in the Bible (Genesis 17:5 and Genesis 17:15 NIV). I don't think expert knowledge is required to answer this question, unless the true answer is not so straightforward. This [handbook](http://integrity.mit.edu/citing-your-sources/what-common-knowledge) suggests that common knowledge does not need to be cited, because common knowledge is something that is widely known. In addition, what I like about this source is that it says that you should be aware of your audience. *Who* is the audience of this website? Are we writing to experts, Christians, pastors, anybody interested in Christianity, or people who know nothing about Christianity?

Comment: How is that possibly "common knowledge?" Most of what is in the bible is not "common knowledge"--and even if it is, it's valuable to provide a reference.

Answer (score 4):

That "answer" is not an answer at all. It does not even begin to answer the question that was asked. It has one fact that may or may not be true (common knowledge or not the source of that knowledge should be noted) but it does not even begin to show where or how that one bit fits into the context of the question.

If you are just answering with tidbits of common knowledge you have mistaken the purpose of this site. We're interested in experts and their knowledge and their ability to apply it to questions, not in regurgitating what everybody knows. That answer does nothing to improve the quality of information available on this topic.

Comment: OK. I'm going to assume that the audience is experts then.